# How to make elements fade in/out when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, scroll

I am working on a website for a friend (https://www.nicoledavis.org) and am having a difficult time getting each section of the website to fade in/out when scrolling up/down. I don't want the text/images to be visible until you scroll down to it.

I have tried this tutorial (https://eddyerburgh.me/animate-elements-scrolled-view-vanilla-js) but am not sure where the animation codes should go in order to tell it which parts to animate.

Here is the HTML code I currently have for each section I'd like to have fade in/out when scrolling:

```
    <div class="main-wrap">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="anchor"><h2><a name="A" class="anchor-link">{anchor-link-1:text}</a></h2></div>
          <div class="anchor-content">{anchor-content-1:content}</div> 
       </div>


    <div class="main-wrap">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="anchor"><h2><a name="B" class="anchor-link">{anchor-link-2:text}</a></h2></div>
          <div class="anchor-content">{anchor-content-2:content}</div>
       </div>
    </div>


    <div class="main-wrap">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="anchor"><h2><a name="C" class="anchor-link">{anchor-link-3:text}</a></h2></div>
          <div class="anchor-content">{anchor-content-3:content}</div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-wrap">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="anchor"><h2><a name="D" class="anchor-link">{anchor-link-4:text}</a></h2></div>
          <div class="anchor-content">{anchor-content-4:content}</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I don't want to remove the anchor feature because that is what makes the website transition smoothly between each section.

I currently don't have anything set up for the animation feature because the tutorial I mentioned above did not work for me. I'm assuming I put things in the wrong places, or am missing something.

I'm expecting to see each container/section to fade in/out when scrolling up and down the website. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the tutorial from the link you provided (https://eddyerburgh.me/animate-elements-scrolled-view-vanilla-js) you simply need to make sure to add the css code for the animation and the js code to trigger the animation on elements.

The tutorial says to add the 'hidden' class to all elements you want to animate.

```js
(function() {
  var elements;
  var windowHeight;

  function init() {
    elements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }

  function checkPosition() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      var positionFromTop = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;

      if (positionFromTop - windowHeight <= 0) {
        element.classList.add('fade-in-element');
        element.classList.remove('hidden');
      }
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkPosition);
  window.addEventListener('resize', init);

  init();
  checkPosition();
})();
```

```css
@keyframes fade-in {
    from {opacity: 0; transform: scale(.7,.7)}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
.fade-in-element {
  animation: fade-in 1.4s;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <h1>VISIBLE</h1>
  <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
    luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
    purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p </div>

  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-wrap hidden">
    <h1>FADE IN</h1>
    <p>Aenean iaculis nunc eget diam euismod feugiat. Nullam nec ligula sed velit iaculis eleifend at sed nisi. Nam nibh ipsum, elementum imperdiet eleifend eget, pharetra et dui. Vestibulum sodales libero at orci rhoncus, nec tempor libero sagittis. Morbi
      luctus dolor ut risus lobortis semper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed vulputate purus. Morbi a urna varius, ornare ipsum ut, laoreet elit. Phasellus mattis, magna et accumsan accumsan,
      purus augue rutrum erat, a ultrices felis felis a neque. Donec consequat pretium eros ac tristique. Pellentesque mollis elementum molestie. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean convallis fringilla suscipit.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Carlos27, that's exactly where I had put the codes when I went through the tutorial, but it still is not fading the way your code above is. I thought I was placing them in the wrong spots, but your code snippet above is working just fine. I'm not sure where the disconnect is with my website.

Comment: @NicoleM.Miller, maybe if you share a link or the code, it would be easier to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Carlow27, I'm not sure which code I should include. If I copied and pasted the codes I used, it would look just like yours above. The difference is that it doesn't do anything at all to the site when the fading codes above are inserted.

Comment: here is the website I added the code to: http://www.nicoledavis.org/

Answer (score 0):

If I am using this code below to keep my anchors and the content that is already present, would the word "hidden" still go after "main-wrap", or would it need to be placed elsewhere?

`<div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="anchor"><h2><a name="A" class="anchor-link">{anchor-link-1:text}</a></h2></div>
    <div class="anchor-content">{anchor-content-1:content}</div> 
  </div>`

Comment: yes, you would have to add the "hidden" after "main-wrap". So here is how it should look like.

<div class="main-wrap hidden">...